# DTO mapper using C# Extension Methods

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, domain-driven-design, extension-methods, dto

Is it a good idea to define the members of a DTO mapper (which is most of the times a static class) as extension methods?

Then instead of writting:

```
Affiliate bo = Mapper.FromDataTransferObject(dto);
```

We may write:

```
Affiliate bo = dto.FromDataTransferObject();
```

*FromDataTransferObject is an extension method defined below:*

```
public static Affiliate FromDataTransferObject(this AffiliateDto dto) {

if (dto == null) {
    return null;
}

var bo = new Affiliate() {
    Id           = dto.Id,
    AccountAlias = dto.AccountAlias,
    Balance      = dto.Balance
    // ...
};

return bo;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naming issues aside, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with it, and it allows for good SOC in terms of where the code lies while still providing a good API.

That said, you should consider renaming your function. Typically, functions are named from the perspective of the *target* (in this case, your DTO), not from the perspective of the *result*. In your case, I would name it `ToAffiliate` or `ToBusinessObject` (if you want to have a consistent name across your DTO's) instead of `FromDataTransferObject`.

Comment: I suggest ToEntity() or ToDto()

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with it, it helps useability and readability, and with the task at hand it doesn't have any side effects either. Used it myself as well already.